# Drupal 8 variables in views grid

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-views, drupal-theming, drupal-8

I'm working on a website (my first using DR8) doing my own Bootstrap based sub-theme. I want to make a product grid with a picture, a short description and a link that opens a modal containing the body of the product.

The problem is I can't access the variables using curly braces ex. {{ column.body }}. The only variable I can use is {{column.content}} and that contains every field I've selected from the views setup.

Is there a way to do this not having to make a lot of hooks in preprocess?

Thankful for any help!

Comment: A little more detail about the view setup and the template you're trying to override would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the details of your view and the template you're working on the fields are likely there just not where you are used to finding them. For better theme debugging in Drupal 8 install the devel module and the kint submodule.

From there put `{{ kint() }}` at the top of the twig file (well anywhere really). Kint will print out the variables that are available to you in that context.

For more ideas [read this article.](https://drupalize.me/blog/201405/lets-debug-twig-drupal-8)